# Send Command to Background Process?

Tags: php, windows, process, background, exec

How can i send a Command to a Background Process with PHP?

**I start the Process like this:**

```
exec('start /D "samp-server.exe"');
```

**I kill the Process like this:**

```
exec('TASKKILL /F /IM "samp-server.exe"');
```

**And i check, if the process is running, like this:**

```
exec('tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq samp-server.exe"');
```

But how can i send a Command, for example "exit" to the Console from this Background Process.

**If you don´t know about Sa-MP Server Console:**

http://www.abload.de/image.php?img=firstd0lc9.png

[http://www.abload.de/image.php?img=thenf3guh.png](http://www.abload.de/image.php?img=firstd0lc9.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use proc__open http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php as this should give you the control you need. Example in the manual page.

Comment: Hmm. But the Examples are bad. proc_open, opens a process? Right? I need to send a Command to a Running Process. ...

Comment: You basically run the command using proc_open, and get a handle to the process. Use this instead of exec. Using this handle you can send commands as if they came from std input, i.e. as if you typed the command on the application, such as "exit" or "quit" etc.

Comment: hmm But i would send the Server in Background... I cant open the Process with proc_open and sending Commands! I would send it to Background AND i would open the Process (by PID) later, if i need it. I couldnt start the Process twice ...  Or what you mean?

Comment: Are you saying you open the process in one php script, and them try to send command in another php script. In which case, it won't work (and not sure what would either). You would still need to have a hold of the process some how